# Select everything older than 48 hours

Tags: php, html, unix-timestamp

I am trying to display user comments from a database that are older than 2 days. This is so I can screen the comments before they appear on the site. The date is entered into the database using CURDATE()

I have tried multiple ways to get this to work, but no joy so far, here's my line of code that tries to compare the dates.

```
$comments = "SELECT comments, initial, surname, theDate " . 
            "FROM tbl " . 
            "WHERE comments IS NOT NULL AND " . 
            "theDate < (unix_timestamp(CURDATE() - interval 2 day)) " .
            "ORDER BY theDate DESC";
```

Everything gets displayed using this method.

Comment: Change `unix_timstamp` to `unix_timestamp`...

Comment: @Ryan: you edited the code, but altered the OP's code from `unix_timstamp` to `unix_timestamp` like I said. How do you know that doesn't solve the problem?

Comment: It wasn't the problem, thanks for fixing my typo on here though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [`DATEDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) MySQL function:

```
SELECT 
    comments, initial, surname, theDate
FROM
    tbl
WHERE
    comments IS NOT NULL
    AND
    DATEDIFF(NOW(), theDate) > 2
ORDER BY theDate DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

use:
    NOT BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY AND CURDATE()
and that should get you everything that is older than 2 days